# How to eliminate bootstrap input-group spacing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set up a straight up input-group with twitter bootstrap 3.
This is the markup code with my actual Razor syntax and below the markup as taken from the documentation:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBox("searchString", "", new { placeholder = "Name or Manufactor or Category", @class = "form-control" })
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Both `input-groups` render as:

[image]

As you can see, this differs from one would expect from the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

Where is the error on my side?

Comment: Your html looks exactly the same as in the documentation, I suspect that it's a CSS problem. Do you have any custom CSS that you apply to any of the classes/elements used?

Comment: Argh ... goddamnit. There was an input styling hidden in my twitter styling. Please form your comment into an answer, so I can reward you properly

Comment: @Serv could you update or add an answer to describe what's the input styling hidden in your twitter styling? I've the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html looks exactly the same as in the documentation, I suspect that it's a CSS problem. Do you have any custom CSS that you apply to any of the classes/elements used?

Comment: Good call, I had some custom CSS like `input:not(.full-width) { max-width: 300px; }`